# How do i use rxjs to ignore second,third button click till my first button click process is complete

Tags: rxjs6, rxjs-observables

My HTML has the following code:

```
button (click)="doFunc()"
```

In my ts-file I have the following:

```
doFunc(){
    this.service.executeAFuncWhichIsAsynchronous().subscribe(x => { updateMyUi(); });
}
```

When I click the button twice, two service calls are made. I don't want this to happen. Instead, subsequent clicks should be ignored.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting a flag before the function call in your state manager (if you're using one) to determine if the call went. Then in your async function if that flag is set, refuse to continue. It would look something vaguely like this

```
import state from './state'

function someAsyncFunc()
{
  if (state.executing) {return}
  else
  {
   state.executing = true;
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log("got here");state.executing=false;return; }, 3000);
  }
}

async function doFunc()
{
  await someAsyncFunc();
}

doFunc()
doFunc()
doFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe to first. https://rxmarbles.com/#first

Like this

```
doFunc(){ 

  this
    .service
    .executeAFuncWhichIsAsynchronous()
    .first()
    .subscribe(x => updateMyUi(x));
```

}

Comment: I implemented the above, the issue is that upon the upon button it executes once , and when i click again after some time no call to this function happens

Comment: Ahh. In your original question you said that you want only first click and subsequent clicks to be ignored.   So what you need to do is either destroy and recreate your subscription after async function is done.  Or use 'debounce' instead of 'first'.  To use debounce your need to share an observable with your asyncFunction.  And your function must trigger an event after has finished running.

Comment: Alternatively and might be a cleaner solution if you just disable the button while async function is running and re-enable it again.  This way you  won't get any click events.

Comment: Here are some references to debounce operator.  https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce.  and https://rxmarbles.com/#debounce